# Raspberry/CubieBoard as MTP media device?

Tags: linux, mtp

I need to connect Raspberry Pi or CubieBoard to my PC as a media device using MTP protocol. Actually I am trying to do USB communication between my PC and Raspberry/CubieBoard. I was not able to find any other way except MTP. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the right platform for these type of questions. You might want to try something like: http://serverfault.com/